# A way to access devise/Warden's auth cookie in a callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, devise, warden

I am using Warden's callback to save certain data into Cookie. 
This is what I have:

```
//This is in devise.rb
Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user, auth, opts|
        auth.cookies[:signed_in] = 1
        auth.cookies[:user_role] = user.role
    end
```

The problem is that when the user signs up for the first time in my web app, this callback does not get called. Thus, I cannot save certain data to cookie and my web app does not run in a correct manner.

I need to make a customized function in user model like following way so it gets triggered after User is made.

```
after_commit :after_sign_up, on: :create
    def after_sign_up
        //need to call below functions over here
        //auth.cookies[:signed_in] = 1
        //auth.cookies[:user_role] = user.role
    end
```

However, i do not know how I can access the same cookie as it was in Warden's callback. Is there a way to access cookie in model? If not, should i access in controller? If so, do I need to add a module in a controller to access it? Detailed explanation would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I believe `Warden::Manager.after_set_user` will do what you are looking for. It is called after a user is created or signs in.

Example:

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user do |user,auth,opts|
    # Your code
end
```